# ClickOnce Deployment, How to Prompt Users with Changelog After App Update?

Tags: c#, clickonce, changelog, ftp-server

I'm using ClickOnce deployment (and an FTP server from Bluehost) for my.NET project, I want to implement a way to inform users about the changes/modifications I made whenever they open the application after an update. I've attempted to use a CHANGELOG.txt file, setting its Build Action to "Embedded Resource," but it doesn't seem to be working.

here is the file it's in the same folder as my project.
[Txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZnef.png)

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please post text directly inside the question and use the formatting tools instead of using a screenshot.